# Writing in a text file from a jsp form

Tags: java, forms, file, jsp

Good morning folks,

I'm using eclipse and learning how to code using JSP, i created a simple form ( code and password) using bootstrap (to make it look nice) and i want each time i click on the button "Se connecter" (submit), to create or add in a text file the time and the name(codeOp.getText()) of the person who clicked.

here's my form (the display is in french sorry):

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <form class="form-signin" action="Page1.jsp" method="GET">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Veuillez vous connectez</h2>
        <label for="codeOp" class="sr-only">Code de l'opérateur</label>
        <input type="number" id="CodeOp" class="form-control" placeholder="Code l'opérateur" ></input>
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Mot de passe</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ></input>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"/> Se souvenir de moi.
            </label>
         </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"/>Se connecter
         </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

and here's the code I'm thinking of adding(or at least something like that):

```
    <% String content = codeOP.GetText(); %>
    <% File file = new java.io.File("log.txt");%>
    <% FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());%>
    <% BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);%>
    <% bw.write(content);%>
    <% bw.close();%>
```

The idea is to create a simple log file that displays the time of each click(can add it later using Date) and the name (CodeOP) of the user who clicked.

It seems simple but I don't know where to write the code since it's discouraged to write java code in a JSP page.

Thanks for reading in advance! Ready to be criticized ;)

Comment: No! don't even think about writing this like java 1.2. Make it inside calls with normal logger!

Comment: JSP are designed to be the View of your web application. If you want to execute a backend opperation (like logging) it would be a better idea to use a Servlet that logs and then forward to your JSP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer folks! 
I knew i  was about to make a mistake xD Can you elaborate a bit more on the use of the servlet for that purpose ? Or is there a way to contact you ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this inline with JSP, you could send this to the backend. You can then on execute that code on the backend. You want to bind your JSP button to an action that goes on behind that. When you have a form and you submit it, this is an action that goes through the "Servlet" which you have created.

Though, your method should be a POST method, not a GET method. So this line `<form class="form-signin" action="page1" method="GET">` should be changed to something like 
`<form class="form-signin" action="Page1" method="POST">`

You don't need to add the .jsp to the action. The action is a parameter that will be passed to our servlet.

You can then in the servlet execute some (normal java) code on the backend when the action matches the one from the form.

To make this a bit more concrete, in your servlet you have a post method. This looks roughly like

```
 public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
       // do something with the form data. 
       // I would use another class for the filewriting though

       String content = request.getParameter('codeOp');
       File file = new File("log.txt");
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile();
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
       bw.write(content);
       bw.close();

    }
 }
```

I wrote this without actually testing this, but it's more to give you an idea of how you would do this. When you have multiple forms, you can use the `ACTION` of the form, to figure out which form has sent the POST request inside your servlet. It'd be wise to actually create some backend classes for all the backend logic, and from your `Servlet` just call some `Facade` class, which can then call the correct class of the backend to create the log etc.

Comment: This looks amazing exatly what i need, i'll work on it and let you know, thanks for the detailed answer bro ! Can i contact you somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an existing webapp logging file?
Try calling log function within jsp page `application.log(String.format("EVENT - User %s, Action %s", "myuser", "click-1"))` and then look for logs files of the j2ee server.

This works for concurrent multiple user requests out of the box, using a custom FileOutputStream you need to make sure it is properly synchronized.

Use grep or similar to collect events from the logging file.

Comment: i actually looked around and read some stuff about the webapp loging but it sounds complicated i just need something simple x)